# how to make Irregular shape uiview and put uiimageview inside those shapes like instacollage iphone app

Tags: iphone, uiview, shapes, frames

I am working on a photo collage iphone app and i have to make irregular shape photo frames inside each shape there will be a uiimageview with gestures, on tapping the shape i need to pick a photo for that shape, these frames are very similar to frames of instacollage iphone app. link : https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/instacollage-pro-pic-frame/id530957474?mt=8

provide me some kind of direction how to do this task.

Thanks

Comment: you might be looking for UICollectionView http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

Answer (score 2):

You can use Mask property of the layer to achieve this.

```
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = self.imageView.bounds ;
UIBezierPath *roundedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:maskLayer.frame];
maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
maskLayer.path = [roundedPath CGPath];

// Add mask
self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sahana. The equivalent code in Swift is:

```
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = self.imageView.bounds
let roundedPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: maskLayer.frame)
maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
maskLayer.path = roundedPath.CGPath
self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```